# Cancel onKey Event from onKey method

Tags: android, listeners

Is it possible to cancel an event from within the onKey method. I only want to allow numbers 0 through 9. If another key was pressed then I want to cancel the key press

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent ev) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(keyCode <30 || keyCode > 39){
               //Cancel Event
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this to restrict input into a text field?  An easier way to do that is to set the [inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) to number, which will cause the number keyboard to appear, and [digits](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits) to true.  I believe this second will restrict input from a physical keyboard..

Comment: Already had numeric set to Integer, but not digits, which actually is a set of valid keys. In my case I set up a resource array of 0 through 9. Works Great! Thanks Mayra

Answer (score 0):

```
if(keyCode <30 || keyCode > 39){
   return true;
} else { 
   return false;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!